# Why won't my Ubuntu 12.04 Preseed file work with LVM

Tags: ubuntu, debian, installation, lvm, preseed

Here is my preseed file:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm_span boolean true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg0
d-i partman/alignment select cylinder
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-root
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                           \
    boot-root ::                                            \
            256 8000 256 ext2                               \
                    $primary{ }                             \
                    $bootable{ }                            \
                    method{ format }                        \
                    format{ }                               \
                    use_filesystem{ }                       \
                    filesystem{ ext2 }                      \
                    mountpoint{ /boot } .                   \
             30000 7000 1000000000  ext4                    \
                    $primary{ }                             \
                    $defaultignore{ }                       \
                    method{ lvm }                           \
                    device{ /dev/sda }                      \
                    vg_name{ vg0 } .                        \
             30000 5000 1000000000 ext4                     \
                    $lvmok{ }                               \
                    in_vg{ vg0 }                            \
                    lv_name{ root }                         \
                    method{ format }                        \
                    format{ }                               \
                    use_filesystem{ }                       \
                    filesystem{ ext4 }                      \
                    mountpoint{ / } .                       \
             256 6000 512 swap                              \
                    $lvmok{ }                               \
                    in_vg{ vg0 }                            \
                    lv_name{ swap }                         \
                    method{ swap }                          \
                    format{ } .                             \
d-i partman/default_filesystem string ext4
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

So why does the installer completely ignore it and choose instead to do this:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg0/root
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                Y8CeAF-SzBy-A3V3-Wvhw-UB0r-r1oE-8sTTuc
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.76 GiB
  Current LE             450
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

    --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/vg0/swap_1
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                63CL5Q-UDAq-zDtn-VrY0-I638-uZ1D-XSkm8E
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```